# Why doesn't this WebGL code render a square on React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webgl

To give some context I'm trying to implement Conway's Game of Life as a mobile app using React Native and WebGL (the expo-gl module); the included code is from some of the modules of this project and targets its rendering to a  component on the app's main screen.  I've verified that the WebGL context gets initialised by testing if I can clear the GLView to a desired colour.  I've used the getShaderParameter and getProgramParameter functions to confirm that the GL shader program has compiled and linked (and passes validation).  I've used the getError function to confirm that the GL error flag doesn't get set.

The app applies the composite model space to clip space transform (that is passed to the shader program) to the vertices of the model in the JS program and outputs the result to the console.  In my understanding of OpenGL this results in a set of vertices that should be renderable, as applying the "divide by w" operation results in vertices with x, y and z components that are all in the range [-1, 1].  However, nothing gets rendered.  Below is the main JS module in question.

```
// This module contains functions that implement the rendering of the game board by determining
// the contents of the corresponding GLView component for each frame.

import {matrix, multiply} from 'mathjs';
import vertexShader from './VertexShader.js';
import fragmentShader from './FragmentShader.js';
import {cellModel, verticalLineModel, horizontalLineModel, modelElements} from './GameBoardModels.js';

// These global variables are assigned values related to the OpenGL context that will be needed to
// render the game board each frame.
var gl;
const glParameters = {
  uniform_modToClip: 0,
  uniform_colour: 0,
  attribute_modPosition: 0,
  vertexBuffer_cellModel: 0,
  vertexBuffer_verticalLineModel: 0,
  vertexBuffer_horizontalLineModel: 0,
  elementBuffer: 0
};

const frontendState = {
  mode: 0,
  cameraPosition: {
    x: 0, y: 0, z: -2
  }
};

// This function generates a 4 - vector translation matrix.
function translate(x, y, z) {
  return (
    matrix([[1, 0, 0, x], [0, 1, 0, y], [0, 0, 1, z], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
  );
}

// This function returns a function that is used to generate the transformation matrix that is
// passed to the vertex shader for each model rendered.
function genModelTransformFunction(x, y, z, frustumScale0, frustumScale1, zNear, zFar) {
  const worldToCamera = translate(x, y, z);
  const cameraToClip = matrix([[frustumScale0, 0, 0, 0], [0, frustumScale1, 0, 0], [0, 0,
                                ((zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar)),
                                ((2 * zFar * zNear) / (zNear - zFar))], [0, 0, -1, 0]]);
  const worldToClip = multiply(cameraToClip, worldToCamera);

  function modelTransformFunction(i, j) {
    const modelToWorld = translate(i, j, 0);
    const modelToClip = multiply(worldToClip, modelToWorld);
    return modelToClip;
  }

  return modelTransformFunction;
}

// This function is called when the corresponding GLView component is first rendered in App.
// It creates the single GL shader program used for rendering the game board and assigns values
// related to the GL context to the global variables gl and glParameters.
function onContextCreation(_gl) {
  _gl.viewport(0, 0, _gl.drawingBufferWidth, _gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  _gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
  _gl.clear(_gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  const vert = _gl.createShader(_gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  _gl.shaderSource(vert, vertexShader);
  _gl.compileShader(vert);

  const frag = _gl.createShader(_gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  _gl.shaderSource(frag, fragmentShader);
  _gl.compileShader(frag);

  const shaderProgram = _gl.createProgram();
  _gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vert);
  _gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, frag);
  _gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
  _gl.validateProgram(shaderProgram);
  const vertStatus = _gl.getShaderParameter(vert, _gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  const fragStatus = _gl.getShaderParameter(frag, _gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  const linkStatus = _gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, _gl.LINK_STATUS);
  const programValid = _gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, _gl.VALIDATE_STATUS);
  console.log("Vertex shader status: " + vertStatus);
  console.log("Fragment shader status: " + fragStatus);
  console.log("Program link status: " + linkStatus);
  console.log("Program validate status: " + programValid);

  gl = _gl;
  glParameters.uniform_modToClip = _gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "modToClip");
  glParameters.uniform_colour = _gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "colour");
  glParameters.attribute_modPosition = _gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "modPosition");
  glParameters.vertexBuffer_cellModel = loadBuffer(cellModel, null);
  glParameters.vertexBuffer_verticalLineModel = loadBuffer(verticalLineModel, null);
  glParameters.vertexBuffer_horizontalLineModel = loadBuffer(horizontalLineModel, null);
  glParameters.elementBuffer = loadBuffer(null, modelElements);
  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

  setInterval(handleRenderEvent, 16.67, frontendState.mode, frontendState.cameraPosition);

}

// This function loads vertex and element drawing data into GL buffers, which will be used to
// perform the rendering for each frame.
function loadBuffer(vertexArray, elementArray) {
  let buffer;
  if (elementArray === null) {
    buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexArray), gl.STREAM_DRAW);
  }
  else {
    buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(elementArray), gl.STREAM_DRAW);
  }

  return buffer;
}

function handleRenderEvent(mode, cameraPosition) {
  const transformFunction = genModelTransformFunction(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z, 1, 1, 0.5, 100);
  renderGameBoard(transformFunction);
}

function renderGameBoard(transformFunction) {
  const testTransform = transformFunction(0, 0);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, glParameters.vertexBuffer_cellModel);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(glParameters.attribute_modPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(glParameters.attribute_modPosition);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(glParameters.uniform_modToClip, false, testTransform);
  gl.uniform4fv(glParameters.uniform_colour, new Float32Array([0, 0, 1, 1]));

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, glParameters.elementBuffer);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  gl.flush();
  gl.endFrameEXP();
  
  if (frontendState.mode === 0) {
    console.log("\ntransform: " + JSON.stringify(testTransform));
    const errorLog = gl.getError();
    console.log("\n:GL error log: " + errorLog);
    
    const cellModel0 = matrix([0, 0, 0, 1]);
    const cellModel1 = matrix([1, 0, 0, 1]);
    const cellModel2 = matrix([1, 1, 0, 1]);
    const cellModel3 = matrix([0, 1, 0, 1]);

    const cellModelClip0 = multiply(testTransform, cellModel0);
    const cellModelClip1 = multiply(testTransform, cellModel1);
    const cellModelClip2 = multiply(testTransform, cellModel2);
    const cellModelClip3 = multiply(testTransform, cellModel3);

    console.log("\n\ncellModelClip0: " + JSON.stringify(cellModelClip0));
    console.log("\ncellModelClip1: " + JSON.stringify(cellModelClip1));
    console.log("\ncellModelClip2: " + JSON.stringify(cellModelClip2));
    console.log("\ncellModelClip3: " + JSON.stringify(cellModelClip3));
    frontendState.mode = 1;

    
  }

}

export {onContextCreation};
```

```
// The GL vertex shader has its own module for clarity.

const vertexShader = `
attribute vec4 modPosition;
uniform mat4 modToClip;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = modToClip * modPosition;
}
`

export default vertexShader;
```

```
// The GL fragment shader has its own module for clarity.

const fragmentShader = `
uniform highp vec4 colour;

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = colour;
}
`

export default fragmentShader;
```

```
// This module contains the vertex data used within GameBoardRenderer to render models.

const cellModel = [0, 0, 0, 1,
                   1, 0, 0, 1,
                   1, 1, 0, 1,
                   0, 1, 0, 1];

const verticalLineModel = [-128, -0.1, 0, 1,
                           128, -0.1, 0, 1,
                           128, 0.1, 0, 1,
                           -128, 0.1, 0, 1];

const horizontalLineModel = [-0.1, -128, 0, 1,
                             0.1, -128, 0, 1,
                             0.1, 128, 0, 1,
                             -0.1, 128, 0, 1];

const modelElements = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3];

export {cellModel, verticalLineModel, horizontalLineModel, modelElements};
```

The console log of the transform test is as follows.

```
cellModelClip0: {"mathjs":"DenseMatrix","data":[0,0,1.0150753768844223,2],"size":[4]}

cellModelClip1: {"mathjs":"DenseMatrix","data":[1,0,1.0150753768844223,2],"size":[4]}

cellModelClip2: {"mathjs":"DenseMatrix","data":[1,1,1.0150753768844223,2],"size":[4]}

cellModelClip3: {"mathjs":"DenseMatrix","data":[0,1,1.0150753768844223,2],"size":[4]}
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode vertex coordinates to fit within -1,1 without any transformations?

Comment: I've now tried this by modifying the vertex shader to not apply the transform and hard coding the model data to the post transformation values shown in the question; there's still nothing being rendered.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the transform was correct but I was passing it to the shader program using the wrong data type, which failed silently.  The uniformMatrix4fv function works as intended if passed a 1 dimensional standard Javascript array but not if passed a 2 dimensional matrix from the mathjs library.  However, accoring to [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context) it does work if passed a value of type mat4 from the glMatrix library.  This is why I'd assumed it would be able to iterate over the matrix type from mathjs that I'd been using.  I've included below the git diff that made this work.

```
   function modelTransformFunction(i, j) {
    const modelToWorld = translate(i, j, 0);
    const modelToClip = multiply(worldToClip, modelToWorld);
-    return modelToClip;
+    let index = 0;
+    const modelToClipArray = Array(16).fill(0);
+    modelToClip.forEach((value) => {modelToClipArray[index] = value;
+                                    index++;});
+    return modelToClipArray;
+  }

  return modelTransformFunction;
```